# Windows Vista: Can see wireless network but can't connect to it

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, connection

I am using an old computer of mine to program with a PCI wireless adapter. It's installed fine, has the correct drivers, and it worked for months. All of a sudden the other day, I can no longer connect to my wireless network. I don't think its the adapter because I can still see the available wireless networks. I just cant connect.

The WiFi in my house works great. I'm actually asking this question using my tablet which is connected to it. The password and SSID of the router didn't change. I have done some research and it seems this is a common issue with Vista and Win7. I tried resetting the IP and some other stuff but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: what error you are getting while connecting

Comment: It just says it cant connect and it asks me if I want to diagnose or choose another network. I tried the diagnosis, it doesnt do anything.